# Component does not receive Data from Service

Tags: angular

I followed the Angular tutorial loosely and tried to receive data from a webserver, which works fine. But in the calling Component, i do not receive any data. I doublechecked my code and compared with the tutorial and from my point of view, everything should be fine.
I receive no errors, can see the data in the console, but i does not appear in the component. Can anyone explain please why i do not receive the data?

This is the **service** function:

```
getProjects(): Promise<Project[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.apiURL)
         .toPromise()
         .then(response => {
             console.log(response.json());
             response.json() as Project[]
         })
         .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and this my **component**:

```
export class FrontpageComponent implements OnInit {

    projects: Project[] = [];

    constructor (private projectService: ProjectService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.projectService.getProjects()
            .then(projects => {
                this.projects = projects;

                console.log(projects);
       });
    }
}
```

My **project** Model currently is just:

```
export class Project {
    dmResponse: Object;
}
```

Comment: add `return` i.e `return response.json() as Project[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your **service**, you should return the value:

```
     .then(response => {
         console.log(response.json());
         return response.json() as Project[];
     })
```

This implicit return on arrow functions only works when the statement doesn't have curly braces. i.e:

```
     .then(response => response.json() as Project[])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know that.