# Why does component not receive data from service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to send data from one component to another via service and followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066905/angular-2-send-data-from-component-to-service). The problem is, that the data never is received by the receiver component. I also tried the solution of that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746456/component-does-not-receive-data-from-service). My other idea why there could be something wrong is that I call the important "commands" in a wrong order. As far as I understand there is a particular order when you work with Observables.

1. create Observable --> private dataSubject = new Subject();
2. call Observable --> subscribe();
3. execute Observable --> next();
4. dispose --> unsibscribe();

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nndzgz?file=src%2Fapp%2Freceiver%2Freceiver.component.ts)

I hope someone can clearify whether I got a wrong understanding of observalbes or if it is just mistake.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple of errors in your solution.

- First of all, always be careful to unsubscribe from a non HTTP observable on destroy.
- When you want to push a value to subject, you should give the value inside `next()`.
- Be aware that after first subscription created, then you are always tracking the name and after each submit, the new value will appears on the screen
- (Optional for Cleaner Code), when a function has side effects, it should not return a value (separate queries from commands).

I created a working example from your stack blitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j5wqa7?file=src/app/receiver/receiver.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you!!! The part with destroy in the service was new to me. So for clarification: In what situations should  subscriptions be called like that? And  what is exactly the advantage of that in comparsion to the "normal" .subscribe?

Comment: When you have an HTTP call, angular take care to unsubscribe on her own. When you are subscribing to Observables to trace data, you should always unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found in your stackblitz example you had issue in the 3rd part of what you above describe in your question.

**3. execute Observable --> next();**

You were not executing your observable all you needed to pass value to your Observable to execute

What you are doing in your service (in stackblitz code example)

```
sendName(name) {
  this.nameSubject.next(); // executing empty observable
  return name; // no need of this if you are setting value in observable
}
```

What you should be doing

```
sendName(name) {
  // notice passing name to observable to execute rather returning
  this.nameSubject.next(name); 
}
```

Update this in your stackblitz example it should work now.